# Automatically set boto content type

Tags: python, boto

I have the following upload code:

```
key.set_contents_from_filename(content)
key.set_acl(acl)
```

I don't know what type of file I'm receiving here, but is there a way to automatically set the content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto library automatically tries to guess the mime type using the Python `mimetypes.guess_type` function but this depends mostly on guessing it from the file name.  If you want to explicitly provide a mime type, you can do that by setting the `content_type` attribute before uploading the file:

```
key.content_type = 'text/html'
key.set_contents_from_filename(content)
```

Does that answer your question?